# Gulp - How to remove duplicated styles in individual css files, If they have already present in common css file

Tags: css, gulp, purge, css-purge

How to remove duplicated styles in individual css files, If they already present in common.css file.

**common.css** file has below styles.

```css
.nav {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**home.css** has below styles.

```css
.nav {
    background-color: red;
}

.home {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Now, I would like to modify the **home.css** using gulp task to remove the duplicated class **.nav** (as I have the class and with the same properties in common.css).
After modifying of **home.css** file, then I'm excepting the below output.

```css
.home {
    width: 300px;
}
```

I don't want to change or modify the **common.css** file. Could you please suggest any node package?

Answer (score 1):

You should think of compiling-merging both your files into one 'main' css file where you could clean-minify-etc.

As there is no 'real gain' of removing duplicated of both files if they arent being used on the same page.

And if they are being used a the same page, could use a minified-merged css file, you would also reduce the amount of blocking calls to render your page as well.

Can concatenate your css files with [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) :

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
 
gulp.task('concat-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('./*.css')
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Can remove duplicates using [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css) or [gulp-clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css) wrapper :

```
gulp.task('minify-css', () => {
  return gulp.src('dist/*.css')
    .pipe(cleanCSS({removeDuplicateRules: 'true'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

So you could end up calling concat-css first, then minify-css and would have a main.css file ready to use without duplicate.